# asp.net mvc5 HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have one project which is configured on IIS. But when am trying to run then am getting Error that

**HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.**

and am trying to resolve this error am write the code in web.config in section .

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

so please give the any solution for that

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because the Web site does not have the Directory Browsing feature enabled, and the default document is not configured. To resolve this problem, use one of the following methods:
Method 1: Enable the Directory Browsing feature in IIS (Recommended)
To resolve this problem, follow these steps:

```
Start IIS Manager. To do this, click Start, click Run, type inetmgr.exe, and then click OK.
In IIS Manager, expand server name, expand Web sites, and then click the website that you want to modify.
In the Features view, double-click Directory Browsing.
In the Actions pane, click Enable.
```

Method 2: Add a default document
To resolve this problem, follow these steps:

```
Start IIS Manager. To do this, click Start, click Run, type inetmgr.exe, and then click OK.
In IIS Manager, expand server name, expand Web sites, and then click the website that you want to modify.
In the Features view, double-click Default Document.
In the Actions pane, click Enable.
In the File Name box, type the name of the default document, and then click OK.
```

Method 3: Enable the Directory Browsing feature in IIS Express
Note This method is for the web developers who experience the issue when they use IIS Express.

To do this, follow these steps:

```
Open a command prompt, and then go to the IIS Express folder on your computer. For example, go to the following folder in a command prompt:

C:\Program Files\IIS Express 

Type the following command, and then press Enter:   appcmd set config /section:directoryBrowse /enabled:true
```